# Django display notifications by day

Tags: django, datetime, date

i have a notification list, and i want to order them by day, meaning, that i want to have in my notification list every day a title like 'Monday 16th od September' and the notifications for that day.
I did not find anywhere how it should be done

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-date-based-archive-day